# Correct payload transformation - Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-el, anypoint-studio

I'm getting:

```
Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]
```

when sending HTTP request.

Situation is like on picture:
 [image]

I pass url query parameters parameters and they are saved in variables, then I use map transformer to build xml request for WS Consumer SOAP request.

When i try to pass parameters like this and to call other web service through soap request:

```
http://localhost:8083/?oib=00025423889&institucijaId=43543500&orgJed=435345395987&svrhaPretrage=3453
```

I get error: Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]

Soap Web service consumer is not getting right payload. Hes expecting correct payload but is not getting it. See picture:

[image]

I think problem is with payload. I don't know why ws consumer is not recognizing the payload?

Here is log:
[link to log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzTNjCFylnNtWkpzeFRRV0M0czA)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the issue is related to the payload. The SOAP server is returning "Connection refused: no further information". Can you verify that you are able to connect to the SOAP server outside of Mule?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the possible reasons:

1) Based from the flow, there is no WSDL call before the transform message. The WSDL call is at the end of the flow.

2) There is a "Connection refused: no further information" message in the log. Is the port for the mule server available? I think there is an application already using that port that's why the connection was refused.

3) Check if the SOAP Server is up. Use a separate client to verify if it's available. It could be down.

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]
```

is returned by the Web Service Consumer componente every time there is a Connection error. In fact, to find the real error, you need to check down the exception in your log (almost at the end), where it says:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

It doesn't seem very explicative as an error. My suggestion is that you check the Connection-config of the WSConsumer component; and try to simulate the call from another platform (I usually use SoapUI) to check if your definition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Previously i also stuck with same bug.

check whether the host your are trying to connect is having any ssl authentication.
check the server logs so that you can get some better view about the reason.

Still could not able to find. Paste your code here.

cheers!